# How to LEFT JOIN the resulting table from a function with another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a user created function that returns a single row table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tempSupplier(int)
RETURNS TABLE (supplier_id int, supplier_name text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY
            SELECT
                suppliers.supplier_id::int,
                suppliers.supplier_name::text
            FROM
                suppliers
            WHERE
                suppliers.supplier_id = $1;
END;$$;
```

I want to LEFT JOIN this resulting 1 row table with another pre-existing table but I'm lost as to how to do it.

```sql
SELECT 
tempSupplier(3).supplier_name, tempSupplier(3).supplier_id, table.scontact_name, table.scontact_title, table.scontact_id

FROM tempSupplier(3)

LEFT JOIN table ON table.supplier_id = tempSupplier(3).supplier_id;
```

I'm not sure how to reference the function results to join with.

Comment: `FROM tempSupplier(3) as ts` then `ts.supplier_id` and `ts.supplier_name`. Though honestly you could get the same result by just joining directly to `suppliers`.

Comment: You should use the sql language instead of plpgsql for this kind of basic function, simpler to write (no BEGIN...END, no RETURN ...) and faster to execute.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the reason I'm not joining it to table suppliers is because I need to join the tables based on 2 conditions. For example function.supplier_id = table.supplier_id AND I need the condition supplier_id = $1. From my understanding I need to split up my queries to achieve this. Joining between a temporary and permanent table is simple enough, but with this approach I would have to constantly alter the temporary table, so I thought a function that could be altered is the best approach

Comment: `... FROM suppliers AS sp LEFT JOIN table ON sp.supplier_id = table.supplier_id WHERE sp.supplier_id = 3;`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote two sample queries for you:

```
-- 1st method 
select * from test_table1 a 
inner join get_data() b on a.table_id = b.table_id;

-- 2nd method
select * from test_table1 a 
inner join get_data_by_id(a.table_id) b on true;
```

I recommend to you using always 2nd method. Performance of second query very hight than the first query. If when you use conditions outside the function then most times DB can not be used indexes. That's why conditions recommended writing inside the function.